# Preselect value on edit in Select 2 in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using vue-select in vue.js

```
<v-select :options="prodItems" @input="setSelected"></v-select>
```

On input i'm getting the items in dropdown but i want to preselect the value on edit suppose in my table if id 2 is saved then in select option with id 2 should be selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `v-model` to bind the value with `selected` variable declared in `data()`.
If there is an initial value for `selected`, then it will be selected by default.

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-select
      :options="prodItems"
      @input="setSelected"
      v-model="selected"
    ></v-select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      selected: { id: 1, label: "P1" },
      prodItems: [
        { id: 1, label: "P1" },
        { id: 2, label: "P2" },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setSelected() {},
  },
};
</script>
```

As you are using objects as options in the array, you can set the default `selected` to `{ id: 1, label: 'P1' }`. I believe you need a `label` attribute in your objects to display correctly in your selector dropdown.

To find the target object in your option array:

```js
const selected = options.find(option => option.id === [target id])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'm passing this array in [ { "id": 1, "name": "P1" }, { "id": 2, "name": "P2"} ] option now on edit i want to select based on id the name should be shown

Comment: So you can set `selected` to the object `{ id: 1, name: 'P1' }` for example. Also, I believe in vue-select you need a `label` attribute to display it in the selector dropdown. Check the updated answer above.  @user3653474